# My update function doesn't work : Spring CRUD API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a CRUD API with Spring to manage students.
Here is my service:

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents(){

        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewStudent(Student student) {
        Optional<Student> studentByName = studentRepository.findStudentByName(student.getName());
        if(studentByName.isPresent()){
            try {
                throw new Exception("name taken");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(Long studentId) {
        boolean exists = studentRepository.existsById(studentId);
        if (!exists){
            throw new RuntimeException("student with id" + studentId + " does not exist.");
        }
        studentRepository.deleteById(studentId);

    }

    @Transactional
    public Student updateStudent(Long studentId, String name) {
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                "student with Id" + studentId + " does not exist"
                )
        );
        if(name != null && name.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(student.getName(), name)){
            student.setName(name);
            return studentRepository.save(student);
        }
        return student;
    }


    public Optional<Student> getStudent(Long studentId) {
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                        "student with Id" + studentId + " does not exist"
                )
        );
        return studentRepository.findById(studentId);

    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();

    }

    @GetMapping(path="/{studentId}")
    public Optional<Student> getStudent(@PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId){
        return studentService.getStudent(studentId);

    }

    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addNewStudent(student);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path="{studentId}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId){
        studentService.deleteStudent(studentId);
    }

    // only update name
    @PutMapping(path="{studentId}")
    public void updateStudent(
            @PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name)

    {
        studentService.updateStudent(studentId, name );
    }
}
```

But when I go on postman, and try to update for example student 3 with this url: http://localhost:8080/api/student/3,
it doesn't change anything, even if the response is 1.

Can anyone helps me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "But when I go on postman, and try to update for example student 3 with this url: http://localhost:8080/api/student/3, it doesn't change anything, even if the response is 1"
Are you calling that endpoint with HTTP PUT or POST?  Please show the body payload.

Comment: I put this in body:{
"id": 3,
"name": "jean",
"age": 22
} , but when I post it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE: I have just been told that mixing @RequestParam AND @PathVariable is perfectly legit, so I guess I stand corrected.  I hadn't seen that before.  Use your best judgement.]

I would not mix @RequestParam AND @PathVariable in the same endpoint.
Even so, try calling

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/student/3?name=Jones
```

Does that work?

Or change your controller method signature to

```
@PutMapping("/{studentId}/{name}")
    public void updateStudent( @PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId, @PathVariable("name") String name)
```

...and call

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/student/3/Jones
```

This may be tangental, but I would abstract out an interface IStudentService (or other naming convention) with just the method declarations, no implementations. Then update the class as

```
public class StudentService implements IStudentService;
```

Assuming that StudentRepository is a Jpa/CrudRepository interface, then in StudentService all you need is

```
@Autowired StudentRepository studentRepository;
```

You don't need that verbose constructor injection.
And in the controller all you need is

```
@Autowired IStudentService studentService;
```

(the name of the interface not the implementation class).

Comment: Yes, I tried with PUT http://localhost:8080/api/student/3/Jones , and it perfectly worked.

Comment: Great @MartinELIAS!
See my video lecture course "Intro to Database App Dev w/Spring Boot, Angular, Postgres" at:
https://www.udemy.com/course/intro-db-app-dev-springboot-angular/?referralCode=3AB74AFDA723F00C4762

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the payload sent with the PUT. In the Controller for the PUT endpoint, you are not using the `@RequestBody`.

You are using only the `@RequestParam` annotation. So with the code you wrote you are able only to change the name by sending it as part of the URL.

Nevertheless, in the request that you are sending you are not specifying the `name @RequestParam`.
If you want to see your code working just send a PUT to this URL: `localhost:8080/api/student/3?name=jean`.

In my opinion you should remove the `name @RequestParam` and add the `@RequestBody` as you are doing in the POST.